# The operation could not be completed devenv /setup

Tags: visual-studio, xaf

I am troubleshooting why my xaf xafml files open in xml instead of the designer
and looking at [the help here](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/B147143/model-editor-opens-xafml-files-in-xml-editor-in-certain-project)

Here is my console output of me trying to run devenv /setup

```
C:\>cd c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE

c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE>devenv /setup

Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Version 15.0.27703.2000.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. All rights reserved.

The operation could not be completed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the issue by running the console as Administrator.

Comment: I gather this is the solution for some people.  More details are at https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T532038/model-editor-missing

Comment: Including the fix for me which was The fix was Tools-> Extensions and Updates->DexExpress.ExpressApp.Design.CorePackage.v18.1-> Enable